# Jquery/JS : How to prevent scrolling in parent element while the child is scrollable (mobile)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to enable scrolling in a child element and disable it for parent elements.
By default when the child scrolling is over the parent starts to scroll, I wish to prevent this default.

I wrote the following code and I don't understand why is it wrong

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
    if (body.hasClass('sliding-menu-open')) {
        if (e.target.id == 'masc') {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else{
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
});
```

In other words, if the body has 'sliding-menu-open' class and the target's id is not 'masc', then prevent the scrolling ability of parents.

I was sure that e.stopPropagation() will do the trick, but obviously it doesn't.

Anyone?

EDIT:
I've created a new sidebar for my website, it is fixed to the top right. It has a lot of content, therefore I need it to be scrollable. BUT when the sidebar is open I want to prevent the content of the page itself to scroll.
I hope now it's clear enough for you understand the problem.

ANSWER:
Well the solution really was adding `overflow: hidden`, the problem was that I have been adding the css to the body, parent or document, when I should add it to the 'html' tag.

Thank's for the help!

Comment: Wait... why not just use css? what are we doing here?

Comment: Edited. I hope it's better now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `overflow:hidden` on the parent element when the body has the class `sliding-menu-open`

```
.sliding-menu-open .parent {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

If you need more help, please provide an example of the html structure or an example jsfiddle

Comment: I can't help more without an example of your html structure. My guess is that if this isn't working, then that means the `.parent` is bigger than another ancestor of its, resulting in that ancestor being scrollable. Mobile has nothing to do with this

Comment: Overflow hidden is really useful for mobile. Indeed the scrollbar is more discret so the display/hide of scrollbar is not visible like on PC. See my post.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `overflow: hidden` property on a the parent element you don't want to be scrolable:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],
    myCurrentElement = document.getElementsByClassName("sliding-menu-open")[0];

myCurrentElement.addEventListener("touchstart", function () {
    body.style.overflow = "hidden";
});

myCurrentElement.addEventListener("touchend", function () {
    body.style.overflow = "";
});
```

You could also add a class that contain the `overflow: hidden` property (and remove it) and other cool stuff.

```
.with-touched-child {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

and JS

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],
    myCurrentElement = document.getElementsByClassName("sliding-menu-open")[0];

myCurrentElement.addEventListener("touchstart", function () {
    body.classList.add("with-touched-child");
});

myCurrentElement.addEventListener("touchend", function () {
    body.classList.remove("with-touched-child");
});
```

---

e.i.

```js
var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0],
    menu = document.getElementsByClassName("menu")[0];

menu.addEventListener("touchstart", function () {
    container.classList.add("with-touched-child");
});

menu.addEventListener("touchend", function () {
    container.classList.remove("with-touched-child");
});
```

```css
body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.container {
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: #f00;
}
.menu {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: #0f0;
}
.with-touched-child {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.with-touched-child .menu {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>Touch and Scroll Me</li>
        <li>Touch and Scroll Me</li>
        <li>Touch and Scroll Me</li>
        <li>Touch and Scroll Me</li>
        <li>Touch and Scroll Me</li>
        <li>Touch and Scroll Me</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Touch, Scroll and no Overflow !</li>
            <li>Touch, Scroll and no Overflow !</li>
            <li>Touch, Scroll and no Overflow !</li>
            <li>Touch, Scroll and no Overflow !</li>
            <li>Touch, Scroll and no Overflow !</li>
            <li>Touch and Scroll Me</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```